# HSQLDB parameter marker not allowed

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, hsqldb

using hsqldb and preparedStatement gives me this Error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: parameter marker not allowed
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

I tried:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Emergency (Id, status, typed, typeb, floor, 
locationX, locationY) Values(CAST(? AS INT), CAST(? AS INT), CAST(? AS 
VARCHAR(50)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(? AS INTEGER), CAST(? AS 
INTEGER), CAST(? AS INTEGER))";
```

And:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Emergency (Id, status, typed, typeb, floor, 
locationX, locationY) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

same error.

EDIT: more code

```
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hsqldb:file:hsqldb; shutdown=true", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        // Alle Kunden ausgeben
        //double help = ((number * pow(2.0, j)) - 1);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Emergency (Id, status, typed, typeb, floor, locationX, locationY) Values(CAST(? AS INT), CAST(? AS INT), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(? AS INTEGER), CAST(? AS INTEGER), CAST(? AS INTEGER))";
        //Id INTEGER, status INTEGER, typeD VARCHAR(50) , typeB VARCHAR(50), floor INTEGER, locationX INTEGER, locationY INTEGER

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setInt(1, Counter.emergencyID);
        pstmt.setInt(2, emergency.status);
        pstmt.setString(3, emergency.typeD);
        pstmt.setString(4, emergency.typeB);
        pstmt.setInt(5, emergency.floorID);
        pstmt.setInt(6, emergency.locationXY[0]);
        pstmt.setInt(7, emergency.locationXY[1]);
        Statement st = null;

        st = con.createStatement();    // statements

        int i = st.executeUpdate(sql);    // run the query

        Counter.emergencyID++;

        if (i == -1) {
            System.out.println("db error : " + sql);
        }

        st.close();
        System.out.println("Eintrag in DB");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am adding all the values and then execute it.

can someone explain me what is goning wrong here?
haven't found anything usefull search.

Comment: show us more code please

Comment: added more code

Comment: `st = con.createStatement();` is wrong. You have to use `pstmt.executeUpdate()` which is what I showed you in the answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to cast your types, you just need to know how PreparedStatement work.
2. You are using Statement and Prepared Statement, but you don't need to Statement, you need just to execute Prepared Statement, so instead use this :

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Emergency (Id, status, typed, typeb, floor, 
                  locationX, locationY) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setInt(1, Counter.emergencyID);
        pstmt.setInt(2, emergency.status);
        pstmt.setString(3, emergency.typeD);
        pstmt.setString(4, emergency.typeB);
        pstmt.setInt(5, emergency.floorID);
        pstmt.setInt(6, emergency.locationXY[0]);
        pstmt.setInt(7, emergency.locationXY[1]);

        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();//execute pstmt no need to st
```